# Correct SHA256 implementation with UTF-8 characters

Tags: hash, utf-8, character-encoding, sha

I'm running into issues comparing SHA256 hashes generated by different languages/functions.

For example, `SHA256("í")` either returns:

```
f3df1f9c358ae8eceb8fce7c00614288d113ad55315f4ebb909774a7daadfc84
```

-or-

```
127035a8ff26256ea0541b5add6dcc3ecdaeea603e606f84e0fd63492fbab2c5
```

Which of the above hash is correct for a string of one character, and what's the correct way of handling UTF-8 strings?

Comment: There's no such thing as a "UTF-8 character". There are Unicode characters, and they can be *encoded* as UTF-8 if you want to. You haven't told us what language you're interested in at all, but basically the process would be to encode the string to binary data using your chosen encoding (e.g. UTF-8), take the SHA-256 hash of that, and then convert that hash back into a string using hex or base64.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Which of the above hash is correct for a string of one character

There is no "correct" answer. What's being hashed is the *bytes*, not the "character". What bytes are hashed exactly depends on the encoding of the string.

`"í"` in Windows-1252 is byte `ED`, which hashes as:

```
f3df1f9c358ae8eceb8fce7c00614288d113ad55315f4ebb909774a7daadfc84
```

`"í"` in UTF-8 is bytes `C3 AD`, which hashes as:

```
127035a8ff26256ea0541b5add6dcc3ecdaeea603e606f84e0fd63492fbab2c5
```

`"í"` in UTF-16LE is bytes `ED 00`, which hashes as:

```
430e2ca27910b5ee6e0ec56a12b81325c763376cb8e25a60362dce9444424f95
```

How exactly that works in various programming languages depends on the languages and the encodings they use for strings.